# Add html elements to webBrowser

Tags: c#, html, winforms

I want to add a `"<div> </div>"` to my webBrowser page.

I've navigated to `http://google.com` for example and I want to add my own `div` on that page, is there a way to do that?

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: No. acually i dont know how to start doing something

Comment: @sagi when you want show tag inside your question you must format properly otherwise you can see it, This time i do it

Comment: You could open the page like google.com inside an iFrame and do whatever you want around it.

Comment: @DanielA.White
I'm just want to add a simple div to the page,
`<a href="http://googlehacked.com" id="hacked"> CLICK ME </a>`
how i want it will be: (on my program) [link](http://i.imgur.com/bHiaPh3.png)

Comment: @BOBLab Yes i iknow, but i want to make a `a` element with javascript method. it will make my life easier

Comment: @MrLister - I want add HTML to google.com, yes. There is no way to do it?

Comment: @MrLister - Im sry mate, someone edit my post and remove the "c#", i need it to my c# program

Comment: Oh... I'm the one who should be sorry. It still had the C# tag, which I missed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a `WebBrowser` control:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Load += Form1_Load;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com");
        this.webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }
    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string content = "<div style=\"background:#f00;\"><h1>HACKED</h1></div>";
        this.webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("gb").InnerHtml = content;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Sagi You are welcome:) By the way, I also edited your question and added winforms tag.

Comment: What if i wanted programmatically insert into the table?

Comment: @Si8 There are different ways to do it. I can think of using [`CreateElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.createelement?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) to create the row and then find the table and add the row using [`AppendChild`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.appendchild?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: @Si8 If you know how to append the row to the specific table using javascript, then another option could be using [`InvokeScript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.invokescript?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

Comment: Are you able to please assist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65292570/why-unable-to-insert-new-rows-to-table-winform

Comment: I posted an answer for [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65292570/why-unable-to-insert-new-rows-to-table-winform).

Comment: Thank you very much