# How to insert a new row into a table in a WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have added the following content to a `WebBrowser` control on form `Load`:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addFirst();
}
private void addfirst()
{
    string html = "<!DOCTYPE html>";
    html += "<html><head><title>NewPage</title>";
    html += "<style>";
    html += "body {font-family: Verdana, Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;} .vtop {vertical-align: top;} table th:nth-child(1) {width: 20%;}";
    html += "table th:nth-child(2) {width: 30%;} table th:nth-child(3) {width: 50%;}";
    html += "</style>";
    html += "</head>";
    html += "<body>";
    html += "<table border='0' id='tableresult'>";
    html += "</table>";
    html += "</body></html>";

    webbrowse.DocumentText = html;
}
```

Then on `Click` event handler of a button I want to create a new `tr` and two `td` elements:

```
var doc = webbrowse.Document;
var elem = doc.GetElementById("tableresult");
var email = elem.DomElement;
var tr = webbrowse.Document.CreateElement("tr");
var td1 = webbrowse.Document.CreateElement("td");
var td2 = webbrowse.Document.CreateElement("td");
tr.AppendChild(td1);
tr.AppendChild(td2);
elem.AppendChild(tr);
```

But when I check the source in the `WeBrowser` control, I don't see the new TR or the TDs.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: You should `Write()` to a new Document object after calling `WebBrowser.Navigate("");`. Make your `addfirst()` method return the html string, then. e.g., `var browser = new WebBrowser(); browser.Navigate(""); var doc = browser.Document.OpenNew(true); doc.Write(addfirst()); var elem = doc.GetElementById("tableresult"); var tr = doc.CreateElement("tr"); [...]`. After that, check the new content: `Console.WriteLine(browser.Document.Body.InnerHtml);`

Comment: I am not navigating anywhere, Just wanted to create my own html page to display inthe WebBrowser control.

Comment: If you don't call `[WebBrowser].Navigate("")` and `[WebBrowser].Document.OpenNew()`, the internal Document is not created. Have you tried what I posted?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky, but you are almost there.

You need to find `tbody` element of the `table` and append the row to that, no matter you have created `tbody` explicitly or not.

**Debug tip:** When you right click on `WebBrowser` control and choose `View Source`, it shows the initial `DocumentText`, not the modified one. If you want to see the updated document text, watch `webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml`.

**Note:** According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#remarks), setting `DocumentText` should be enough; when you set `DocumentText`, it navigates to `about:blank` and then loads the document content based on the text which you have set. So all the expected things like creating Document object or raising Navigating, Navigated or `DocumentComplete` events happen. Following the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/WebBrowser.cs,6f4f482860b505d7) also shows the same.

**Example**

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var html = @"
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head><title>NewPage</title></head>
        <body>
            <table id=""tableresult"">
                <thead>
                    <th>Column 1</th>
                    <th>Column 2</th>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>";
    webBrowser1.DocumentText = html;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tr = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("tr");
    var td1 = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("td");
    td1.InnerHtml = "value 1";
    var td2 = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("td");
    td2.InnerHtml = "value 2";
    tr.AppendChild(td1);
    tr.AppendChild(td2);
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("tableresult")
               .GetElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].AppendChild(tr);
}
```

Comment: If you watch `` in the `Load` event handler, you will see it's still null, that's because it will be set after finishing the processing of the current message. To show its value in a MessageBox in `Load` event, after setting the `DocumentText` you can see the updated content like this: `BeginInvoke(new Action(() => { MessageBox.Show(webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml); }));`.

Comment: I didn't have a `tbody` so i figured it wasn't needed. Thanks for the heads up. I don't have a `thead` so can I just leave that out from the original string?

Comment: As it's already mentioned in the answer, you don't need to add a `tbody` inside the table. it will be there, no matter you add it explicitly or not. So the sample code will work in both case, having or not having tbody. `thead` is also not necessary, it will work without `thead` as well.

Comment: @Si8 Let me know if the post answers your question.